# Caused by: kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.widget.TextView in fragments

Tags: android

```
class DashBoardFragment : Fragment() {

    private var recyclerView : RecyclerView?=null


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        var view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dash_board, container, false)

        initComponents(view )


            return  view
        }

        private fun initComponents(View view) {



            var textView : TextView = view?.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView) as TextView
            textView.setText("hello world")  
    }
```

**when changing into recycler its showing same problem appreciate if you help to me**

Well, how about adding more details. Like, what are you trying to accomplish, how are you doing it, what difficulties you have found with the approach, another approaches you have tried, etc. In summary, without code isn't a good question neither is with just code. Search for the balance!

Comment: If you think an answer solved the problem for you, you should accept it by clicking the tick mark next to the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try moving the code in the `initComponents` function to the `onCreateView` function. The error might occur because `recyclerView` id is not ready until the `View` is created.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        var view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dash_board, container, false)

        var textView : TextView = view?.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView) as TextView
        textView.setText("hello world")


        return  view
    }
```

Comment: Thanks its working fine but i didn't get  what the issue..when im creating new function and calling  it from its not working

Comment: The `onCreateView` method is called when the views are being created. You have to initialize all the views of a fragment inside this method, else they will be set to `null`. This is why it was not working inside the `initComponents` method.